# JavaScript - Why can functions have properties?

Tags: javascript

Consider the piece of code below.
The type of exports is **function**. But we can still have `exports.hello` property. How is that possible??

```
const obj = {
    exports: {}
}
obj.exports = () => {
    console.log('invoked')
}
obj.exports.hello = () => {
    console.log('hello() invoked')
}
var output = `type of obj => ${typeof obj} #### 
type of obj.exports => ${typeof obj.exports} ####
obj.exporst.hello() is ${typeof obj.exports.hello}
`;
console.log(output);
```

The output is:

```
type of obj => object #### type of obj.exports => function #### obj.exporst.hello() is function
```

It is logical to have an `exports` object (`typeof 'object'`) and have functions like `exports.hello`, `exports.foo`, etc. But how can we have exports itself as function and then have properties of exports?

Comment: javascript is a strange and a beautiful creation

Comment: Each function is an object as well - it has a constructor function (named as weird as possible, of course, - `Function`). Yes, `typeof` returns different value, but it's more about weirdness of `typeof` (consider `null` case).

Comment: Javascript by far isn't the only language with this trait.

Comment: Consider the much simpler case that every function has a number of build-in properties and methods by default, e.g. `foo.bind(bar)`, `foo.length`… https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to **[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)**

> In JavaScript, functions are `first-class objects`, because they can
>   have properties and methods just like any other `object`. What
>   distinguishes them from other `objects` is that functions can be called.
>   In brief, they are `Function` objects.

And this is self sufficient to explain why you can have properties of a function

Check **[this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)** on the properties and method of function objects

to Summarize what the MDN documentation state

> The global `Function object` has no methods or properties of its own.
>   However, since it is a function itself, it does inherit some methods
>   and properties through the prototype chain from `Function.prototype`.

In short a `function is an instance of an Object`

```js
function myName() {
   console.log('myName')
}

console.log(myName instanceof Object);
```

Answer (score 3):

Functions are Objects. Anything you can do to an Object, you can do to a Function.

Comment: I'd add `alert instanceof Object // true`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is highly dynamic-typed language, so this behavior is not surprising. Just think about JavaScript functions as about objects which can be called.